# One empty dummy-file copied and saved with names from a list

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to do this in osx terminal:
I have a list (**test.txt**) containing around 700 unique file names. These unique file names needs to be saved one-by-one to one empty image file ( eg. 700 x 1225 px). I have created the empty file with the name **empty.jpg**.
I have read about the `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` but can't figure how to work with these commands! 
I was thinking that the list (test.txt) and the image (empty.jpg) schould be in the same folder and that the output will be saved in that location.
Anyone who can help a newbie at this …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution on my issue using a perl script running in Terminal:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my $filetobecopied = "empty.jpg";

my $filename = 'test.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
chomp $row;
print "$row\n";
copy($filetobecopied, $row) or die "File cannot be copied.";
}
```

Works as expected!